# How do i save photos in NEF format on my Nikon D3300?

Tags: nikon, raw

How do I set my Nikon D3300 up to save photos in the NEF format? It currently saves in JPEG, but have done some research and it seems like RAW provides better quality images. I have read the user manual and it doesn't tell me how to change it.

Comment: Be aware that RAW format doesn't automatically give you better images. RAW format is just a more suitable format for manipulating image data in post-processing - a process which can allow you to possibly produce better images.

Answer (score 1):

It's under *Image Quality* settings on the *Information Screen* that is covered on page 10 of the *[D3300 User's Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/payY500AHbkQ02bXMhb14TZo4978/D3300_NT(En)02.pdf)*.

For more detailed information, you can download the *[D3300 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/E7vrv00ZwHJt02sHgtZ15XIHOb30/D3300RM_(En)03.pdf)* where image quality selection is covered on pages 85-86.

[image: D3300 Reference Manual p.85]
[image: D3300 Reference Manual p.86]

You can also access the *Image Quality* setting using the *Menu* button and selecting the *Shooting* tab.